# can we swallow unhandled exception in windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am using windows service in c# for file transfer using sFTP (ssh.net).
I have handled exception in each and every block of code still i am getting unhandled exception and my my windows service gets crashed.

i figured out about unhandled exception by using

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException
```

Is is possible to avoid this unhandled exception and avoid service from being crashed.

Thanks in advance.
Vijay

Comment: Provide the stacktrace of the exception. Also an example of how you handled exceptions manually will be appreciated.

Comment: If you add a catch-all-exception handler somewhere, you are not solving the problem, and are controlling the symptoms. It is better to fix the error.

Comment: Exceptions should be either handled or prevented, not eaten...

Comment: Exception will not thrown if i do it for first time, but if i repeat same steps twice or thrice the exception goes unhandled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because [`UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) does not change the fact that the process is going down. It just gives you the chance to do something (e.g. log the failure) before that happens.

Even if things could work like that, the fact is that your service has bugs. You should be looking more to fix them and less to hide them.

Comment: Behavior of service is like that, if i have started file transfer and in between if router powered off then it will surely throws an exception, and that i have handled but still it goes unhandled. dom't knbow why ?

Comment: If it's unhandled then obviously you have not handled it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is is possible to avoid this unhandled exception and avoid service from being crashed.

Yes, it is. It is also a bad design decision.

> AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException

This is a good place to put in a last resort handler that writes a crash report, then restarts the service.

Swallowing exceptions is not smart. EVERY exception you expect has to be handled.

> I have handled exception in each and every block of code still i am getting unhandled 
>   exception

Sounds like you do not know what you are doing. It is not necessary to handle exceptions in every code block - it totally overloads your code with exception handlers. It is necessary, though, to have proper exception handling where it makes sense and to catch EVERY SENSIBLE (expectable) exception.

Avoiding the service from crashing is not smart - because if you do not know what exception you have, then you may end up with a corrupt service instead of a crashed one. Fail fast and hard is still the ONLY way to write reliable server systems.

Comment: I am transferring file on sFTP router and there are chances of router to not connecting, router powered off in between the process. so it will cause an exception. i have logging mechanism as well so i figured out that the exception which i have handled that  is being thrown again.

Comment: No, sorry. Most run down to 2-3 base exceptions. Network is not an unknown scenario. THere should reall not be THAT many exceptions in THAT many places that a competent programmer could not fix them all. INn the relevant code part you may even have a catch (Exception) - but ONLY there, not anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to avoid an unhandled exception is not to have one! Assuming your service doesn't make use of any multi-threading capabilities which could throw exceptions on separate threads, you can get away with putting an exception handler around your ServiceBase.Run call

This way any exceptions that slip through can be caught at the very last minute and handled. Usually though you want to try and grab these lower down and handle accordingly

With threaded applications it becomes a little more difficult as each new thread that is spawned won't throw on the main thread and won't be handled by this 'catch-all' handler.

Edit:

I might add that I don't condone doing this - ideally you should be handling exceptions in the right places - if you are getting unhandled exceptions you aren't expecting, then you need to examine the stack and see what went wrong. Adding a handler to AppDomain.UnhandledException and writing the exception tree and stack to the log will help (you do have some logging mechanism, right?). Either that or debugging